# Get container name in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to get the container name.

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_secret_pw_shh
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: devuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: devpass
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  web:
    build: ./php-app
    container_name: php_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

and inside my dockerfile php-app I would like to get php_web

Comment: Not sure it's possible - Dockerfiles are used to create docker images, so I don't think they even have a concept of "the name of the container that docker-compose is going to run the image that is being built by this Dockerfile" - it's really out of its scope. I'll propose a workaround in an answer soon

Comment: To repeat @Omer's comment more decisively: you can't, because you can run the same image multiple times with multiple container names.  What's the higher-level task that would need to know this?

Comment: I mean I need the container names, imagine I have docker-compose.dev.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml and each one have a container name per example php-app-dev and php-app-prod, and in the docker file of /php-app I need to get the name, sounds clear for you?

Comment: But what the specific need of getting these containers name might be other possibility if you explain it more

Comment: Yes you are right, I will put Args as explained below and to keep as simple as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible workaround - it doesn't really automatically access the name of the container from inside the Dockerfile - but it allows you to define that name in a single place (the `.env` file) and then access that variable inside the `docker-compose.yml` and even pass it on to the `Dockerfile` so it can use it as well.

Here's the workaround:

Create a file called `.env` in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file and write the container name inside:

```
APP_CONTAINER_NAME="php_web"
```

Change your docker-compose.yml file as follows:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_secret_pw_shh
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: devuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: devpass
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  web:
    build:
        context: ./php-app
        args:
            APP_CONTAINER_NAME: ${APP_CONTAINER_NAME}
    container_name: ${APP_CONTAINER_NAME}
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Inside your `php-app/Dockerfile`, preferably near the top, add the line:

```
ARG APP_CONTAINER_NAME
```

You can now access this variable inside the Dockerfile.

For example, to create a file inside the container with the same name as the container, do:

```
RUN touch ${APP_CONTAINER_NAME}
```

Comment: I accept you solution, but I won't use I think I will put my specific names in the args